# Platonic love?愛情

Tags: translation, word-choice

Can i say  that i love a sibling using
愛情 or is it for romatic love?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use 愛情 to refer to familial love, but it's typically used to describe love from parents to children, or from people to pets. For example 彼女は両親からたくさんの愛情を受けて育った is perfectly fine, but 娘から親への愛情 and 姉妹同士の愛情 are much less common, if not wrong. It's also a fairly big word that should be used sparingly. 愛情 may be a good word when you formally make a comment on works like *Little Women*, but if you just want to say "I love my brother/sister", using 愛情 would probably sound embarrassing.

Answer (score 3):

I think 愛情 is a really stiff term to express love in casual conversation. You can reserve 愛情 when discussing love as an idea or social context.

When it comes to expressing love for a sibling, as opposed to romantic love, you can use 好｛す｝き or 大｛だい｝好｛す｝き.

> 兄｛にい｝さんは大｛だい｝好｛す｝きだから、いい誕生日｛たんじょうび｝プレゼントを上｛あ｝げたい。
>   Because I love my brother, I want to give him a good birthday present.

Beware of using 恋 or 愛 in this kind of context, as it can have an incestuous air about an expression.